# How to debug the white screen of death in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have recently upgraded my ASP.NET MVC application from beta to version 1. And true enough, after I fixed all the references, I got a white screen of death when I pressed F5.

Is there any idea how to debug white screen of death in VS 2008?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a few of these mysterious issues by [turning on view compilation](https://devermind.wordpress.com/2009/05/03/aspnet-mvc-tip-turn-on-compile-time-view-checking/). This will catch some hard-to-debug problems that aren't caught with the default build process.

You can also [hook up](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx) the [Elmah error logging](https://code.google.com/archive/p/elmah/) component. It will keep a record of your exception so you have a copy of the stack and exception while you go digging around for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new ASP.NET MVC v1 application and compare how the two are setup.

I would pay special attention to the web.config and global.asax.

HTHs,
Charles

Comment: Including the web.config in the views folder

Comment: That was what I did at the end to solve my problem. Although this is a sure-fire solution, but I would still prefer a simpler, less laborious one.

Comment: Surely it wasn't that laborious using WinMerge or something like that...? Otherwise I hope you don't have too many projects to migrate!