# Blank LogOn view in MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

On Friday I gave a demo of an MVC application using the `Authorize` attribute on my `JobCardController`, and all was well.  This morning, when I attempt an unauthorized action, I still get redirected to the `LogOn` view, using the below URL, but I appear to have what my reading tells me is called a White Screen of Death, i.e. nothing but white background and no actions invoked.

```
http://localhost:34054/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fJobCard
```

**ADDENDUM:**
I forgot to mention that I have moved the Account models and services out into my DataObjects and Services projects, but I had done this last week already without this problem.

I'm not asking what is wrong, but what are the common faults that could cause something like this and how can I start debugging this mess?

**SOLVED:**
Somehow an Authorize attribute had landed up on my whole controller class, as in,

```
[HandleError]
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : BaseController
```

I removed that and everything is working again.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "White Screen of Death"? What exactly happens when you go to LogOn view?

Comment: When I go to LogOn, I get a plain white screen and no actions are invoked.  I picked up the term from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910487/how-to-debug-the-white-screen-of-death-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: ProfK - You should post your solution as an answer and mark it accepted.  This might help someone in the future with a similar problem :)

Comment: @Tommy, I was about to do that when I saw your comment, hehe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow an Authorize attribute had landed up on my whole AccountController class, as in,

```
[HandleError]
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : BaseController
```

So, the controller was being repeatedly hit by an unauthenticated user for the same action invocation.  I'm surprised this didn't cause some sort of 'stack overflow' condition.